# how to assigne value to RbConfig::CONFIG

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to build ruby gem. I need to change values set in rbconfig.rb in my gem file extconf.rb.
I do not want change rbconfig.rb

as example new values defined in extconf.rb should look like:
`RbConfig::CONFIG["CC"] = "gcc"` 
`RbConfig::CONFIG["CXX"] = "g++"`

Is there a way to do that instead modifying rbconfig.rb ?

Comment: You don't modify `RbConfig::CONFIG`. If you're compiling your code through `mkmf`, pass the value of `CC` through `make` instead.